# python list matching for multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex, list, match

I have a python 2-D list **my_list** having string elements. I want to find the nested lists that match the **pattern_list** and want to remove the matched nested list.

```
my_list = [['UserName', 'EmailID', 'NoofLogins', 'Logs'], 
           ['abrretrerfe2', 'abarrett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abarrett has logged in successfully. \n'], 
           ['adminadminerfdDcm', 'user@comp-test.in', 2.0, 'User : Admin has Prince comp logged in successfully']
           ['adminadminerfdDcm', 'user@liveonlinecloud.info', 2.0, 'User : Admin Harry liveonline has logged in successfully']
          ]

pattern_list = ['comp-test.in', 'liveonlinecloud.info','alertdomain.in']
```

for example, from the above list, i want the resultant list to be as follows

```
result_list = [['UserName', 'EmailID', 'NoofLogins', 'Logs'], 
               ['abrretrerfe2', 'abarrett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abarrett has logged in successfully. \n']
              ]
```

the 2nd and 3rd nest lists in **my_list** are removed because, their value matched one of the patterns.
In the first case, comp-test.in was matched. In the second case liveonlinecloud.info matched.

Can anyone help me with this? -- Thanks for all your helps guys

### Another case:

```
the_list = [['UserName', 'EmailID', 'NoofLogins', 'Logs']
           ['abariettq7g3sab9s2', 'abariett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abariett has logged in successfully. $$'],
           ['adminadswdasdpj362xQ', 'admin@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ Scan Started Successfully for - Account Name : windacademy.us. $$']
          ]

valid_pattern = ['started', 'initiated', 'stopped', 'added', 'fetched', 'completed', 'deleted', 'updated', 'disabled']
```

from the `the_list`, I want only  the lists that match any item in the `valid_pattern` list

```
output_list = [['adminadswdasdpj362xQ', 'admin@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ Scan Started Successfully for - Account Name : windacademy.us. $$']
              ]
```

See in `output_list`, the only 1 nested list that matched a pattern element **started**. How do I get this output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that without regex, I assume that the pattern can be at any index in a nested list not just 1:

```
result_list = my_list[:] 
for l in my_list:
    tmp = '_'.join(map(str,l))
    for pattern in pattern_list:
        if pattern in tmp:
            result_list.remove(l)
            break
```

Comment: This is destructive to the original list, not sure the OP was looking for that given they created a separate `result_list`

Comment: Thanks @alivar!! Just curious, How can I have the opposite result, like I want the resultant list having only nested list that matches the pattern list.

Comment: You can construct that list in couple of ways, for example you can add this line after the for loop `opposite_results= [l for l in my_list if l is not in result_list]` is this what you want?

Comment: No.. I wanted only the nested lists that matches the `pattern_list` to be there in the `result_list`.

Comment: @alivar: Please look into the edited question now. I have added the scenario I described.

Comment: `new_case = [l for l in my_list for pattern in valid_pattern if pattern in '_'.join(map(str,l))]` this gives you the list of sublists that match a pattern in valid_pattern

Comment: @alivar : The code you gave is not working. I just checked it in a online python console too. It returns output as a null list. Any idea why?

Comment: The code in comment above or the code in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

A simple list comprehension would work in this case:

```
result_list = [row for row in my_list if not any(p in row[1] for p in pattern_list)]
```

Comment: Once one gets two double loops in a list comprehension, I'd be careful about using the adjective "simple" for a list comprehension.

Comment: True, but the `any` test could be factored out as a simple function :)

Comment: @AChampion : Your solution worked too!! Thanks a lot. What if I had to have the just the lists that match the pattern, rather than removing them?

Comment: @KouBoy Remove the `not` in the condition.

Comment: @AChampion : I have explained another case I was looking for in the question, Sir. Can you look into it and help me out?

Comment: It works for that too, remove the `not` change the `row[1]` to the appropriate index, i.e. `row[3].tolower()` (changing it to all lower case)

Comment: @AChampion : It didn't work. It returns Null list, even though there are matching lists. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['UserName', 'EmailID', 'NoofLogins', 'Logs'], 
           ['abrretrerfe2', 'abarrett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abarrett has logged in successfully. \n'], 
           ['adminadminerfdDcm', 'user@comp-test.in', 2.0, 'User : Admin has Prince comp logged in successfully']
           ['adminadminerfdDcm', 'user@liveonlinecloud.info', 2.0, 'User : Admin Harry liveonline has logged in successfully']
      ]
pattern_list = ['comp-test.in', 'liveonlinecloud.info','alertdomain.in']

result_list = []
for row in my_list:
    for pattern in pattern_list:
        if pattern not in row[1]:
            result_list.append(row)
```